# How to use the YouTube iFrame API in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: firefox, iframe, google-chrome, youtube, youtube-api

I have a YouTube video [embedded on my site using an iFrame](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html). I want to use [the API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html) to pause the video, but in Chrome I get an error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://subdomain.example.com/ from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/KmtzQCSh6xk?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://subdomain.example.com. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

In Firefox (3.6) I get this error:

```
Permission denied for <http://www.youtube.com> to call method Location.toString on <http://subdomain.example.com>.
```

I've tried putting the iFrame in myself or adding it with the API. Either way the player gets in, but I have no API control over it.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '433',
        width: '731',
        videoId: 'KmtzQCSh6xk'
      });
}

$("#pause_button").click(function(){
  alert("Pausing " + player);//is undefined :(
  player.pauseVideo();
});

</script>
```

How do I get browsers to allow the YouTube iFrame to access my page's main frame?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Ignore those warnings. The player should still work fine regardless.
2. Use the recently-introduced [JavaScript Player API for iframe embeds](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/01/introducing-javascript-player-api-for.html).

Comment: I still get the error using the JavaScript Player API for iframe embeds. I even tried their code in their playground with their browser.